# Javascript Regex match Alphanumeric where number is not limited in one digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been researching all day regarding this but I cannot find a solutions. Apologies I am new in RegEx even in Javascript.

I have a string (space in the last is included):

```
var str = "/ ( ( C * 20 ) + 100 ) + C ";
```

and all I want is to get the alphanumeric but not limited in one digit.

I tried this:

```
strOutput = str.match(/\w/g);
```

my output is `["C", "2", "0", "1", "0", "0", "C"]`

my requirement is `["C", "20", "100", "C"]`

It seems so simple but I cannot find answer. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `+` quantifier after `\w` to match one or more occurances of a word character. Without `+` quantifier, it would match single character at a time.

```
> var str = "/ ( ( C * 20 ) + 100 ) + C ";
> str.match(/\w+/g);
[ 'C', '20', '100', 'C' ]
```

Comment: @Avinash_Raj I can't believe that was only it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

see this regex demo https://regex101.com/r/vV2gT7/2

```
/([\w\d]{1,})/g

"/ ( ( C * 20 ) + 100 ) + C ".match(/([\w\d]{1,})/g)
```